# hadoop-mapreduce reducer-combiner input

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I'm learning some MapReduce but I'm running into some problems, here's the situation:
i've two files:
"users" contains a list of users with some of their data (gender,age,country,etc...) the file looks like this:

```
user_000003  m  22  United States   Oct 30, 2005
```

"songs" contains data of songs listened by all the users (userid, date and time of listening,artist id, artist name, song id, song title):

```
user_000999 2008-12-11T22:52:33Z    b7ffd2af-418f-4be2-bdd1-22f8b48613da    Nine Inch Nails 1d1bb32a-5bc6-4b6f-88cc-c043f6c52509    7 Ghosts I
```

the goal is to find the k most listened song in certain countries. with k and a list of countries provided in input.

I decided to use the MultipleInputs class for the mapper so one mapper will output a set of key-value pairs that looks like this: . the other mapper will output . as far as I know i should be able to read all the values paired with a certain key (so I should find the country and a certain number of songs in the list of values associated with a userID) in the reducer and output a set of file with  pairs to be red by another MapReduce job.

I'm pretty sure the mappers do their job as I was able to write their output with the reducer.

UPDATE: the files are passed to the mappers with the following code:

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);

        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(songsFile), TextInputFormat.class, SongMapper.class);
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(usersFile), TextInputFormat.class, UserMapper.class);

        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outFile));
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setJarByClass(Songs.class);

        job.setCombinerClass(Combiner.class);
        job.setReducerClass(UserSongReducer.class);
```

Mappers code:

```
public static class UserMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{

        //empty cleanUp()

        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String record = value.toString();               
            String[] userData = record.split("\t");
            if(userData.length>3 && !userData[3].equals(""))
            {
                context.write(new Text(userData[0]), new Text(userData[3]));
            }        


        }

        //empty run() and setup()

    }

    public static class SongMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{

        //empty cleanUp()

        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String record = value.toString();               
            String[] songData = record.split("\t");
            if(songData.length>3 && !songData[3].equals(""))
            {
                context.write(new Text(songData[0]), new Text(songData[5]+" |||  "+songData[3]));
            }        


        }

        //empty run() and setup()

    }
```

Combiner code:

```
public static class Combiner extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> 
    {

        private boolean isCountryAllowed(String toCheck, String[] countries)
        {

            for(int i=0; i<countries.length;i++)
            {
                if(toCheck.equals(countries[i]))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {



            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();



            String country = "foo";
            for(Text value : values) 
            {
                if(!value.toString().contains(" ||| "))
                {
                    country = value.toString();
                }else
                {
                    list.add(value.toString());
                }

            }

            if(isCountryAllowed(country, context.getConfiguration().getStrings("countries")))
            {

                for (String listVal : list) 
                {
                    context.write(new Text(country), 
                            new Text(listVal));
                }
            }

         }
    }
```

The problems comes when I try to output the  pairs with the reducer:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {


             for (Text value : values) 
            {
                context.write(key,value);
            }
            }

         }
```

I used " ||| " to build the artist+title string
the problem is that country remains "foo". I think I should see at least one row of the output with the correct nation as the key but the output it's always "foo" (2,5kb songs file):

```
foo Deep Dish |||  Fuck Me Im Famous (Pacha Ibiza)-09-28-2007
foo Vnv Nation |||  Kingdom
foo Les Fleur De Lys |||  Circles
foo Home Video |||  Penguin
foo Of Montreal |||  Will You Come And Fetch Me
foo Godspeed You! Black Emperor |||  Bbf3
foo Alarum |||  Sustained Connection
foo Sneaker Pimps |||  Walking Zero
foo Cecilio And Kapono |||  I Love You
foo Garbage |||  Vow
foo The Brian Setzer Orchestra |||  Gettin' In The Mood
foo Nitin Sawhney |||  Sunset (J-Walk Remix)
foo Nine Inch Nails |||  Heresy
foo Collective Soul |||  Crowded Head
foo Vicarious Bliss |||  Limousine
foo Noisettes |||  Malice In Wonderland
foo Black Rebel Motorcycle Club |||  Lien On Your Dreams
foo Mae |||  Brink Of Disaster
foo Michael Andrews |||  Rosie Darko
foo A Perfect Circle |||  Blue
```

what am I doing wrong?

PS I should be able to avoid the second job if I use a custom combiner, does the combiner act exactly like a reducer?

Comment: the details about your mappers are missing. Please provide them because something might already be wrong there.

Comment: Note that since a combiner is never guaranteed to be called, it cannot solve any problem.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the complete job configurations for the two jobs. Especially the parts where you defined the mappers. Are you also defining the OutputFormat somewhere? I would add some System.out.println in the beginning of the reducers to see which values are coming in.

Comment: @jacopo: I removed my answers since I wasn't aware of the MutlipleInputs functionality..

Answer (score 1):

From your code I see, The country should alwayes be "foo", What are you exactly trying to achieve?

```
 // IN YOUR MAPPER THE VALUE IS WRITTEN USING |||

context.write(new Text(songData[0]), new Text(songData[5]+" |||  "+songData[3]));

// THEN VALUE WILL ALWAYS CONTAIN ||| AND WILL NEVER CHANGE THE COUNTRY THAT WAS SET TO TRUE
 String country = "foo";
     if(!value.toString().contains(" ||| ")) //never ---
```

And then you are outputting the country variable:

```
 context.write(new Text(country),
```